# MYSQL Using AND and OR on selecting data from database

Tags: php, mysql

i would like to select * data from this table just to display everything according to my filter selected.

My Table:

tbl_reservation

```
res_id | trans_code |   status | order_type   |    type_of_order  | date_ordered
------ | -----------|----------|--------------|-------------------|-------------
  1    |   111-111  |Delivered | For Delivery | Online Transaction|2016-10-09
------ | -----------|----------|--------------|-------------------|-------------
  2    |   111-112  |Delivered | For Pick-up  | Online Transaction|2016-10-09
------ | -----------|----------|--------------|-------------------|-------------
  3    |   111-113  |Cancelled | For Delivery | Online Transaction|2016-10-09
------ | -----------|----------|--------------|-------------------|-------------
  4    |   111-114  |          | For Purchase | Online Transaction|2016-10-09
------ | -----------|----------|--------------|-------------------|-------------
  5    |   111-115  |          | For Pick-up  | Walkin Transaction|2016-10-09
------ | -----------|----------|--------------|-------------------|-------------
  6    |   111-116  |          | For Purchase | Walkin Transaction|2016-10-09
------ | -----------|----------|--------------|-------------------|-------------
  7    |   111-117  |Delivered | For Pick-up  | Walin Transaction |2016-10-09
------ | -----------|----------|--------------|-------------------|-------------
  8    |   111-118  |Delivered | For Delivery | Online Transaction|2016-10-08
------ | -----------|----------|--------------|-------------------|-------------
  9    |   111-119  |Delivered | For Pick-up  | Online Transaction|2016-10-08
------ | -----------|----------|--------------|-------------------|-------------
 10    |   111-110  |Cancelled | For Delivery | Online Transaction|2016-10-08
------ | -----------|----------|--------------|-------------------|-------------
 11    |   111-100  |          | For Purchase | Online Transaction|2016-10-08
------ | -----------|----------|--------------|-------------------|-------------
 12    |   111-101  |          | For Pick-up  | Walkin Transaction|2016-10-08
------ | -----------|----------|--------------|-------------------|-------------
 13    |   111-102  |          | For Purchase | Walkin Transaction|2016-10-08
------ | -----------|----------|--------------|-------------------|-------------
 14    |   111-103  |Delivered | For Pick-up  | Walin Transaction |2016-10-08
```

My Form:

```
<form method="post" action="">
<select name="filter">
<option value="Today">Filter Data for today</option>
<option value="Yesterday">Filter Data for yesterday</option>
</select>
<input type="submit" value="Filter"/>
</form>
```

MY PHP CODE TOGETHER WITH MY SAMPLE QUERY ON GETTING FILTER

```
<?php
//inclue db connection

if(isset($_POST["filter"])){
$get_filter = $_POST["filter"];
if($filter == "Today"){
  $sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tbl_reservation WHERE status = 'Delivered' OR status = 'Cancelled' OR status = '' AND DATE(date_ordered) = DATE(now()) ");
}elseif($filter == "Yesterday"){
  $sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tbl_reservation WHERE status = 'Delivered' OR status = 'Cancelled' OR status = '' AND DATE(date_ordered) = DATE(now())-1 ");
}


//THEN DISPLAY ALL IN VARIABLE USING WHILE LOOP AS mysql_fetch_array
//Display data here
//..
//..
//..
?>
```

Date Order = 2016-10-09 [For today]
Date order = 2016-10-08 [For yesterday]
There is no error.
When I choose filtering for today..it displays all data together with the data for yesterday
But when I choose for yesterday.. it display all data together with the data for today

What i was hoping is to correct the data query. Can someone help? thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you subtract 1 from a date, it does not have the effect you intend: MySql then converts the date to a number and subtracts 1 from that. This will not give the expected result on the first of the month.

So use `date_add` or `date_sub` instead of `-1`, for example:

```
date_sub(date(now()), interval 1 day)
```

Secondly, the logical operator `and` has precedence over `or`, so when you write this:

```
WHERE status = 'Delivered' 
   OR status = 'Cancelled' 
   OR status = '' 
  AND date(date_ordered) = date(now())
```

It is evaluated as:

```
WHERE status = 'Delivered' 
   OR status = 'Cancelled' 
   OR (status = '' AND date(date_ordered) = date(now()))
```

... which means the date condition is not playing any role when that status is Delivered or Cancelled.

You can solve this by adding parentheses around the `OR` part, or you can benefit from the `IN` operator:

```
WHERE status IN ('Delivered', 'Cancelled', '')
  AND date(date_ordered) = date(now()))
```

.. and for the second SQL statement:

```
WHERE status IN ('Delivered', 'Cancelled', '')
  AND date(date_ordered) = date_sub(date(now()), interval 1 day)
```

Comment: thank you for the information sir. your statement on using IN gave me another knowledge on query statement. nice explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Will this work?

```
SELECT * FROM tbl_reservation WHERE DATE(date_ordered) = DATE(now()) AND (status = 'Delivered' OR status = 'Cancelled' OR status = '')
```

Comment: havent tried this one yet.. but ill try debugging my codes for this.. hope it works.. fingers crossed.. ahahaha

Comment: it works.. i didnt know that you could put parenthesis for the status.. thx so much..

Answer (score 0):

you should use date_sub

```
  SELECT * 
  FROM tbl_reservation 
  WHERE status = 'Delivered' 
  OR status = 'Cancelled' 
  OR status = '' 
  AND DATE(date_ordered) = DATE_SUB(now(),INTERVAL 1 DAY)
```

could be also that the status is null  (not = '')

```
  SELECT * 
  FROM tbl_reservation 
  WHERE status = 'Delivered' 
  OR status = 'Cancelled' 
  OR status  is null 
  AND DATE(date_ordered) = DATE_SUB(now(),INTERVAL 1 DAY)
```

Comment: I have tried using DATE(date_ordered) = DATE(now()) and it still works for me sir.. but when i added the OR statement for selecting status,.. i think it contradicts the mysql statement

Comment: Could be the status is null. i have update the answer

Comment: yes sir. thank you. i have debugged my codes and tried +Boris Savic's code.. i didnt knew that you could enclose the status with () and seperate it with AND operator.